# Running Docker pull command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and trying some things. Now I want to create a Dockerfile, which build automatically the Oracle DB image.

```
############################################################
# Dockerfile to build MongoDB container images
# Based on Ubuntu
############################################################

# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Example McAuthor

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

################## BEGIN INSTALLATION #####################
CMD docker pull alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
```

My problem is the `docker pull` command.
When I try to use the `RUN` command, the docker daemon say, that he can't find '`docker`'. Then I use the `CMD` command, and it works, but is that correct? Maybe you can show me alternative ways.

Answer (score 14):

You should not pull from a Dockerfile.

You simply can start your Dockerfile with:

```
FROM docker-oracle-xe-11g
```

And add in it any Oracle config file which you would need in your own Oracle image.
The `docker-oracle-xe-11g` Dockerfile is already based on ubuntu.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.1
```

Comment: If i use the "FROM docker-oracle-xe-11g" , i get these error message:Error: image library/docker-oracle-xe-11g:latest not found

Comment: @user2068694 Try in your docker session a `docker pull docker-oracle-xe-11g` first.

Comment: yeah i know that works, but i hoped, that i can trigger this via a dockerfile....because i had to rollout this for a few pcs

Comment: @user2068694 you can rollout from a few PC the same docker image, based on top of `docker-oracle-xe-11g`, without having to pull anything from the Dockerfile itself.